# Checking for duplicate tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I have a html file:

```
<html>
<html>

</html>
</html>
```

And I am trying to read this file using beautifulsoup in my test.py file , where i am testing for any duplicate html tags. I have below assert condition which check whether a html tag exists or not but do not have any condition to check whether there are duplicate html tags in a single file.

```
def testing(self):
    try:
        assert self.soup.find('html') != None
    except AssertionError, e:
        raise Exception("HTML Tag is missing!")
```

How can I include this in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify an [html.parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), find all `html` tags and check how many have you found.

Here's an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


invalid = """<html>
<html>

</html>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(invalid, 'html.parser')
print len(soup.find_all("html"))  # prints 2

valid = """<html>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(valid, 'html.parser')
print len(soup.find_all("html"))  # prints 1
```

In your test it would be:

```
assert len(self.soup.find_all('html')) == 1
```

Also, instead of using `assert` in this case, better use unittest's [self.assertEqual()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual): it has a `msg` argument which will help you make your test more readable and pythonic:

```
self.assertEqual(len(self.soup.find_all('html')), 1, msg="HTML Tag is missing!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert len(self.soup.findAll('html', recursive=False)) == 1` should work.